# useForm how to setValue for dynamic input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

Hi I have Form create using `useForm` I have Api will return data like this

```
const createQuestion = {
    _id: "da2sd3dsa5d56a5sdd5as48d4a94949",
    framework: "hard",
    benchmark: "hard",
    difficulty: "hard",
    questionType: "mcq",
    mcqAnswer: [
        { answer: "ali", id: 1, checked: true },
        { answer: "moh", id: 2, checked: false },
        { answer: "jem", id: 3, checked: false },
    ],
    questionHeader: "good job!",
    Keywords: ["one", "two"],
    selectCorrectAnswerTrue: false,
    selectCorrectAnswerFalse: true,
    articleAnswer: { answer: "good place to do" },
};
```

`mcqAnswer` is an array I want to set this value when return from API set in form inputs

setValue for inputs

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data != null) {
        setValue("mcqAnswer", data?.mcqAnswer.answer);
        setValue("selectCorrectAnswer", data?.mcqAnswer.checked);
    } else {
        // setValue("isTeacherEnabled", false);
        console.log("error in set values");
    }
}, [data]);
```

this is `McqQuestion` component
the value for `Editor` is `mcqAnswer.answer`
and the value for input is `mcqAnswer.checked`

```
<FormControl id="type" style={{ wordBreak: "break-word" }}>
    <Editor
        {...register(`mcqAnswer`, { required: true })}
        theme="snow"
        className="pt-0.5 border rounded-md border-gray-200 w-full"
        value={mcqAnswerWatch}
        placeholder={t("Enter your question")}
        onChange={mcqAnswerChange}
    />
</FormControl>
<FormControl id="type">
    <div className="flex">
        <div className="flex w-1/2 mr-5">
            <div className="block w-full">
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 mt-1 text-sm">
                    <div className="flex">
                        <input
                            {...register(`selectCorrectAnswer`, { required: false })}
                            data-id={answerId}
                            ref={inputRef}
                            className="form-check-input checked:bg-blue-600 checked:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none"
                            type="checkbox"
                            // id="selectCorrectAnswer"
                            // {...rest}
                            onChange={e => {
                                handleCheckboxChange(
                                    e.target.checked,
                                    inputRef.current.getAttribute("data-id")
                                );
                            }}
                        />
                        {mcqAnswerList.map((answer: any, i: any) =>
                            answer.id == inputRef?.current?.getAttribute("data-id") &&
                            answer.checked == true ? (
                                <label
                                    key={i}
                                    // htmlFor="selectCorrectAnswer"
                                    className="flex items-center text-xs font-semibold text-black cursor-pointer">
                                    {t("The correct answer")}
                                </label>
                            ) : (
                                ""
                            )
                        )}
                    </div>
<div
                    className=""
                    onClick={_ => {
                        handleDeleteMcqQuestion(mcqRef.current.getAttribute("data-id"));
                    }}>
                    <label id="remove">
                        <Remove />
                    </label>
                    <label
                        htmlFor="remove"
                        className="text-[#757D8A] cursor-pointer">
                        {t("Remove")}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</FormControl>
```

I am creating a input form using this function

```
    const handleCreateMcqQuestion = () => {
        setMcqAnswerList(
            mcqAnswerList.concat({
                question: <McqQuestion />,
                id: mcqIds,
                checked: false,
            })
        );
    };
```

how to create a loop to put the data in form when data received from API

my form like this

[image]

I want check if api return data if API return data I want fill data into inputs like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set error for a particular form field using `setError()` method from `useForm()` hook.

```
setError('registerInput', { type: 'custom', message: 'custom message' });
```

[Official Documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/seterror/)

Comment: thank you bro for your help but actually I want to create `map` to loop through array of data come from API and put data in the input